# How to configure Web Page Kiosk with Android Management API

Tags: android-management-api

I have tried deploying a web page as a kiosk app on a fully managed device enrolled via QR code. following the example configuration at
https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices#kiosk_mode
resulting in the following policy json:

```json
"applications": [
 {
   "packageName": "com.google.enterprise.webapp.<my-webapp-id>",
   "installType": "KIOSK",
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
 },
 {
   "packageName": "com.android.chrome",
   "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
   "managedConfiguration": {
     "URLBLacklist": ["*"],
     "URLWhitelist": ["<my-webapp-host>"]
   },
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
 }
]
```

Upon deploying a device with the policy it produces the following compliance error

```json
​"nonComplianceDetails": [
{
 "nonComplianceReason": "INVALID_VALUE",
 "packageName": "com.google.enterprise.webapp.<my_webapp_id>",
 "settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities"
}
]
```

And produces the following error info on the device "persistentPreferredActivities 4"
How would I resolve this error and fix this policy deployment?

Answer (score 3):

When you set the installType of an app to `KIOSK` then you should no longer use `persistentPreferredActivities` in the policy as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies?hl=en#persistentpreferredactivity). You may also want to start using the new managed configuration keys of Chrome (URLBLacklist to [URLBlocklist](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#URLBlocklist) and URLWhitelist to [URLAllowlist](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#URLAllowlist) as the [older naming](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#URLBlacklist) convention was deprecated in v101).